# multiple setup method using unit test in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

Hi At present my python unit test case is in following pattern,

```
create some setup in "def setUpClass(cls):"
multiple test case method as "def test_*(self):"
And delete created items in "def tearDownClass(cls):"
```

Now my scenarios changes in the following way,

```
create some setup in "def setUpClass(cls):"
multiple test case method as "def test_*(self):"
How to perform some operations which is created in setup?
Again multiple test case method to validate "def test_*(self):"
And delete created items in "def tearDownClass(cls):"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you give an example or further clarify what it is exactly you want to do‽

Comment: In python unittest module there is a concept called setUpClass (this will be executed at the start of the test always) , After this all validation method will be executed. Now in my case once all validation methods are completed it should again perfrom some setup and then proceed with other validation methods

Comment: I think you just need to add some helper methods to your test class or maybe an inner class.

Comment: If you have sets of test methods in a test case class that need different setups and/or tear downs then you may have put tests into one class that shouldn't be together. Split it up into several classes. The order isn't guaranteed anyway and there may be test runners executing more than one test method in parallel.